# What determines which "Feature" is shown in the Field Calculators example section?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to change what "Feature" is selected on the bottom of the Field Calculator? In the picture the example would be "See" from the property type column. Could I change it to the property number?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The *Feature name* of the *Output preview* in the *Field Calculator* dialog is called **Display Name**, and can be configured in the *Display tab* of the *layer Properties*.

It is documented here: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties

The documentation for the *Expression Builder interface*, which is embedded in the *Field Calculator* dialog, is here: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#the-interface